# Android application and inter-app file access

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-permissions

Hi I have been tasked with investigating the feasibility of developing an anti-malware app for Android. I am led to believe that Android apps run in their own 'sandbox' and have no permissions to scan outside that sandbox.

How is it then, that apps (eg. antivirus) already exist that must be able to test files in other apps' areas? I don't imagine an antivirus program would be very effective if it could not test files phone-wide. How would this be done?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that an app is run in their own 'sandbox' but it doesn't mean it is confined to not access outside the sandbox. I'm assuming by sandbox you mean the apps virtual machine or something of that sort.

For instance you can exchange information and talk back and forth between 2 apps using Intents, which lets you grab information from one app into the other. Again there are 2 ways of looking into it, this can be considered as a feature which lets you access outside stuff or as a security vulnerability. Which leads back to glass half-full or half-empty scenario.

I'm not sure if I understand your dilemma correctly. But hope this helps.